# How do I set the default opening method of a deb file to be in software centre?

Tags: 22.04, software-center, deb

When I try and install a deb file, Ubuntu opens it in archive manager. Although I can click on other options and choose to open it in software center, it doesn't change to default or even give me an option. Is there any way to change this behavior?

The name of the file is `discord-0.0.21.deb`. Other files this works with include `Minecraft.deb` and `steam_latest.deb`

Comment: I would recommend this article that provides different options. https://itsfoss.com/install-deb-files-ubuntu/

Comment: Thanks @mondotofu! It worked